# Обращение к форме на чужом сайте

Tags: html

Всем привет.

Есть сайт (не мой), на нем есть input, в которые можно вписать что-либо (поиск) и кнопка.  Как можно при нажатии на своем сайте на кнопку, обратиться к чужому сайту, заполнить там этот input (естественно нужно как-то его найти), эмитировать нажатие кнопки?

P.S. Обратиться уже к странице поиска чужого сайта, вписав нужные значения в адрес страницы - не вариант.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите исходный код того сайта. Вам важны значения в атрибутах name в input'ах на том сайте. У себя создаете форму с action на тот сайт, а input'ы с name такими же, как и на том сайте. Пример:

```
<form method="post" action="[ссылка на страницу сайта, где находится форма]">
   <input type="text" name="INPNAME" />
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Все. Теперь при нажатии кнопки "Отправить" пользователя отправит на тот сайт с заполненной формой

Comment: Да, а если нажимающий человек авторизован на чужом сайте и там нет проверки на REFERER, то тогда уже будет CSRF.

Comment: @ОлегАрхипов, для поисковых форм вполне сработает.

Comment: @ОлегАрхипов `<form method=get action=//yandex.ru/search>
  <input type=search name=text>
  <input type=submit value=Search>
</form>`